# Scala - wrapping functions with default parameter values

Tags: scala, overriding, default-parameters

I am using a library function which uses a default parameter value for parameter minPartitions. I have a wrapping function from which I call this library function. The way I want my wrapping function to work is - if a value is passed for the minPartitions, I will use this value when calling the function. Else, I will let the default value be used and not pass the parameter. How do I do this in Scala?

```
def read(foo: String, minPartitions: Integer = ????): RDD[String] = {
  val rdd = sc.hadoopRDD(jobConf,
            classOf[InputFormat],
            classOf[BytesWritable],
            classOf[BytesWritable],
            minPartitions // optional - default value will be used
        ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Reuse the default value. i.e. do minPartitions= to the same value as in the definition of hadoopRDD
2. Make minPartitions an Option[Integer] and then you know when it is defined and when not.
3. Make two versions of the function.

I would go with option 1 if you have a logical default of your own or don't really care if the default might change at one point in the future and use option 2 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Scala has the concepts of `Option` for values which might not be present.

An `Option[Int]` can either be a `Some[Int]` or `None`. You can use that in your wrapper function.

Also... When working with Scala, use `Int` instead of `Integer` unless explicitly required.

Now... one way is to use pattern-matching

```
def read(foo: String, partitionsOpt: Option[Int]): RDD[String] = {
  partitionsOpt match {
    case Some(partitions) => sc.hadoopRDD(
        jobConf,
        classOf[InputFormat],
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        partitions
    )
    case None => sc.hadoopRDD(
        jobConf,
        classOf[InputFormat],
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        classOf[BytesWritable]
    )
}
```

Another is to `map` the `Option` and then do a `getOrElse`

```
def read(foo: String, partitionsOpt: Option[Int]): RDD[String] = {
  partitionsOpt
    .map(partitions => sc.hadoopRDD(
        jobConf,
        classOf[InputFormat],
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        partitions
    ))
    .getOrElse(sc.hadoopRDD(
        jobConf,
        classOf[InputFormat],
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        classOf[BytesWritable]
    ))
}
```

Comment: And perhaps overload it with `def read(foo: String, partitions: Int) = read(foo, Some(partitions))` and `def read(foo: String) = read(foo, None)` for convenience and make it feel more like a "default param" for the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Example function:

```
//you can directly define your default in the parameter list
def read(minPartitions: Integer = 123): Unit {
    println(minPartitions)
}

read(77) //prints out 77
read() //prints out 123
```

Alternatively, you can use Option/Some/None as mentioned in another answer.

Example function:

```
//in this function, you must provide an Option value to second parameter
def read(minPartitions: Option[Int]): Unit {
    println(minPartitions.getOrElse(123))
}

read(Some(77)) //prints out 77
read(None) //prints out 123
```

You can also use these two concepts together (define the parameter type as an Option and provide a default value in the parameter list)

Hope this helps! :)